# Dynamic multiple/single activesheet referencering for scatterchart plotting

Tags: vba

i am trying to code a macro that allows me to select a few cells to be plotted on a scatter chart.

but currently i can only hard code the sheet name from where I select the cell entries for charting.

I hope to be able to change the hard coding to allow for dynamic sheet reference.

This should allow multipe cell selection from different sheets and then plotting their values into the scatter chart.

I attach the code below for your advise. TQ
Issue now about hard coded sheet name: 
 .Name =  "='US Sector (2)'!" & MultiSel.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1)
hope to change to
 .Name =  "=[dynamic sheet reference]!" & MultiSel.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1)

```
Sub ChartUSA()
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+y
'
    Dim MultiSel As Range
    Dim addr, cellAdd_name, cellAdd_Xaxis, cellAdd_Yaxis As Variant
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    cnt = 0

    ' make sure a range is selected
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

     'For Each cnt In Selection
     For Each MultiSel In Selection
     cnt = cnt + 1

     'ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart USA").Activate
     Sheets("ChartUSASX").ChartObjects("Chart USA").Activate
     ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select

     With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
         .Name = "=ws!" & MultiSel.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1)
         .XValues = "='US Sector (2)'!" & MultiSel.Offset(0, 24).Address(False, False)
         .Values = "='US Sector (2)'!" & MultiSel.Offset(0, 25).Address(False, False)

        .MarkerSize = 10
        .ApplyDataLabels
        .DataLabels.Select
         Selection.ShowSeriesName = True
        Selection.ShowValue = False
        .MarkerSize = 10

     End With


    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `MultiSel.Parent.Name` will give you the sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ChartUSA()

    Dim MultiSel As Range
    Dim cht As Chart

    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub

    Set cht = Sheets("ChartUSASX").ChartObjects("Chart USA").Chart

    For Each MultiSel In Selection.Cells
        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = "=" & RangeAddress(MultiSel)
            .XValues = "=" & RangeAddress(MultiSel.Offset(0, 1))
            .Values = "=" & RangeAddress(MultiSel.Offset(0, 2))
            .MarkerSize = 10
            .ApplyDataLabels
            With .DataLabels
                .ShowSeriesName = True
                .ShowValue = False
            End With
            .MarkerSize = 10
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Function RangeAddress(rng As Range) As String
    RangeAddress = "'" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Address(False, False)
End Function
```